# How to use super() in this complex multiple inheritance situation?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiple-inheritance, python-3.3

I'm writing a library that provides subclasses of each of two existing base classes with extra functionality.

Rather than explain the arrangement in words, here's a diagram:

[image: Diagram]

And minimal code:

```py
class Base0:
    pass

class Base1(Base0):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.foo = something()

class Base2(Base0):
    pass

class Mixin:
    def __init__(self, bar):
        self.bar = bar
        # More code

class Child1(Base1, Mixin):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Base1.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        Mixin.__init__(self, some_function_of(self.foo))

class Child2(Base2, Mixin):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Base2.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        Mixin.__init__(self, something_else())
```

The `Base` classes are outside my control. I wrote the `Mixin` and `Child` classes. Users of my library will subclass the `Child` classes, so it's very important that the inheritance be sane and correct.

What I'd like to do is use `super().__init__` in the `Child` classes rather than explicitly invoking the `Base` and `Mixin` initializers. The reason this is nontrivial is that in `Child1`, the value passed to the `Mixin` initializer can't be determined until after the `Base1` initializer has run.

What is the simplest/sanest way to set this up?

Comment: I think that what you have is about the only way for the `Childx` class to implement their `__init__()` methods.

Comment: This sounds kind of like `Mixin`'s functionality shouldn't be implemented with a mixin. If you really want it to be a mixin anyway, it may be best to put that initialization somewhere other than an `__init__` method - you don't want it interrupting `super` chains.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica How else would it be implemented?

Comment: For the "put that initialization somewhere else" approach, just some other method with a different name that the child class `__init__`s call. Maybe call it `set_bar` or `_mixin_init` or something.

Comment: For the "not a mixin" approach, it depends on what this mixin's functionality actually is.